# Нажатие Button внутри CardView в списке RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

У меня есть список `RecyclerView` который состоит из большого количества `CardView`, которые заполняются динамически внутри `CardView` есть  кнопка `Button`.
по нажатию по `CardView` открывается детальная информация, а по нажатию на `Button` нужно поставить лайк этой записи, не открывая детальную информацию.
Проблема в том что по клику на `Button`  открывается детальная информация как по нажатию на `CardView`. Button отрабатывает как положено только если нажать на кнопку и подержать палец на копке как бы лонг клик, но нужно что бы обычный клик.

CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postTitle"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postBody"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/postLike"
                android:text="@string/like_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerItemClickListener

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
}
```

AdapterRecycler

```
public class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecycler.ItemViewHolder> {
private List<Posts> postsList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private IContentProvider iContentProvider = IContentProvider.getInstance();

public void setPostList(List<Posts> postsList, Context context) {
    this.postsList.clear();
    this.postsList.addAll(postsList);
    this.context = context;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public Posts getItem(int i) {
    return postsList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postsList.size();
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_post, parent, false);
    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(v);

    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Posts posts = getItem(position);
    Users users = iContentProvider.getUserInfo(posts.getUserId());
    holder.postBody.setText(posts.getBody());
    holder.postUserName.setText(users.getUserName());
    holder.postTitle.setText(posts.getTitle());
    if (posts.getLike() == null) {
        holder.like.setEnabled(true);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iContentProvider.likePost(posts.getId());
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder.like.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView postTitle;
    TextView postBody;
    TextView postUserName;
    Button like;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postBody);
        postUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postUserName);
        like = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLike);
        postTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Может вам не нужен RecyclerItemClickListener и вы можете его убрать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  а как без него отрабатывать нажатие по CardView?

Comment: точно так же как и на все другие обычные Вью.. с помощью OnClick обычного... У вас задача снаружи адаптера повесить слушатель нажатий на ячейку? Если да, то ваш спсоб - неправиьный и излишний совсем.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  мне нужно обработать нажатие как по кардвью так и по кнопке которая внутри кардвью
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-OFtmgizBNHQ2hLa0dEaEhSQ2M

Comment: По ссылке левой не пойду. Обраатывайте нажатия в адаптере. Повесьте один слушатель на карточку, второй на кнопку - они не будут конфликтовать. Слущатели тача тут не нужны совсем

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  по ссылке скриншот с эмулятора как оно должно  выглядеть .
В смысле в адаптере в методе onBindViewHolder повесить  setOnClickListener на кардвью и на батон?

Comment: Скриншот надо в вопрос добавлять картинкой, не ссылкой на внешний ресурс. Да, именно так - setOnClickListener на все нужные элементы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  да это помогло) спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте элемент который состоит отдельно из CardView и поверх него отдельно кнопка, чтобы карточка не перехватывала нажатие кнопки.

Кнопка не должна быть внутри карточки.

Я так думаю )

Comment: как это реализовать?

Comment: покажите файл R.layout.card_post